# Is there any difference between linking an IBAction from StoryBoard to the ".h" file or the ".m" file?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I noticed that when I link an IBAction to a .h file, it will automatically also be placed in the .m file. That makes sense.

But if I link an IBAction to the .m file, it won't be placed in the .h file. Is there a reason for this? And are there any differences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only difference is the property visibility. Putting the property inside the .m file is like setting its visibility to private (mind that, private not protected) instead in the .h it's like having its visibility set to public.

Comment: But doesn't something need to by `public` in order to be linked from `StoryBoard`? Or am I making that up? I'm pretty sure I read that somewhere... o.O

Comment: Actually I think (but not sure about that) that the linking between the storyboard and the property happens in the -initWithCoder: method. Inside that method all the properties (both privates and publics) are visible since it is called from the class implementation.

Comment: Objective-C doesn't support public/private properties. You can do public/private/protected instance variables, but all properties are public. However placing them inside the .m file makes them "secret". They are there if anything simply assumes the property exists, but you'll get a warning if you try to use them in code. It's a common best practice to put properties in the .m file if nothing outside the class needs to use it, this means it is fairly safe to simply delete or rename the property or change it's type, without breaking other code. I've never done this with IBAction but it will work

Answer (score 1):

It's usually better that it be private (i.e. inside the *.m* file only), because you wouldn't want some other class to be able to call what is supposed to be an action method called by your button.

The ability of the button to "find" the method at runtime has nothing to do with where it is declared (*.h* or *.m*); Objective-C is dynamic. What is recorded inside the nib is merely the name of the selector (e.g. `myAction:`); all you're doing in the nib is causing `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` to be sent to the UIControl after it is instantiated when the nib loads. When the event *occurs* (e.g. the user taps the button), that `action:` message will be sent to the target object no matter where the `myAction:` method is declared - and indeed, it will be sent even if the `myAction:` method doesn't exist (in which case we will crash).

Comment: And see my discussion here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch07.html#_action_connections